# Setting rotation point and center animation in CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation

I got a problem with a CSS-Animation:

```css
.windmill {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 60 55" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <g id="base"">
                                    <polyline id="body" fill="black" points="15.039,30.666 15.383,14 16.639,14 16.98,30.666"/>
                                </g>
                                    <g class="windmill">
                                        <polyline id="wing_x5F_top" fill="black" points="15.811,0.213 15.161,10.06 15.452,12.378 16.208,12.382 16.839,10.034 16.143,0.215"/>
                                        <polyline id="wing_x5F_left" fill="black" points="27.41,19.574 19.182,14.129 17.023,13.232 16.646,13.886 18.372,15.598 27.244,19.861"/>
                                        <polyline id="wing_x5F_right" fill="black" points="4.645,19.402 12.873,13.957 15.031,13.06 15.409,13.714 13.683,15.426 4.811,19.689"/>
                                        <circle id="motor" fill="#333333" stroke="#E6E6E6" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="15.976" cy="13.232" r="1.15"/>
                                    </g>
                                </svg>
```

Please help me I need to center the animation and also make sure that it's no double rotation..
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the browser does miscalculate the width and height. Although I think JavaScript is as on option, it will usually have the downside of not supporting hardware acceleration. Which is quite visible when increasing the rotational speed. A jpg version will probably be pretty hard to implement since of missing transparency, positioning, loss of responsiveness...

I found a workaround by adding hidden circle with the size of the rotor blades, to the group that is being animated.

```css
.windmill {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-animation: clockwise 1s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: clockwise 1s infinite linear;
    animation: clockwise 1s infinite linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes clockwise {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes clockwise {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 55" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polyline id="body " points="15.039,30.666 15.383,14 16.639,14 16.98,30.666 " transform="matrix(1.2953083,0,0,1.2953083,-4.694094,-0.881751)" style="fill:#000000" />
    <g class="windmill">
        <circle r="16" cy="16" cx="16" id="ellipse4307" style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:0;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none" />
        <path style="fill:#ae0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none" d="m 15.99036,0.001184 a 16,16.11449 0 0 0 -0.293467,0.0101 l -0.341537,12.264949 0.635004,3.923873 -0.0026,0.04048 0.0051,-0.01771 0.0026,-0.02025 0.637535,-3.923873 -0.344066,-12.26242 a 16,16.11449 0 0 0 -0.28841,-0.01518 l -0.0051,0 -0.0051,0 z m -0.0026,16.239421 -0.01771,0.0101 -3.653175,1.399035 -10.2132018,6.413292 a 16,16.11449 0 0 0 0.298528,0.523689 l 10.5522088,-5.808647 3.01817,-2.519779 0.02025,-0.01269 -0.0026,-0.0026 0.0051,-0.005 0.0076,-0.0076 -0.01518,0.0101 z m 0.0051,0.0051 0.03289,0.02025 3.01817,2.52231 10.542089,5.801057 a 16,16.11449 0 0 0 0.313706,-0.516098 l -10.218303,-6.413293 -3.650643,-1.401564 -0.02782,-0.02025 -0.0026,0.0026 0.0101,0.01269 -0.01518,-0.0101 -0.0026,0.0026 z" id="path4286" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </g>
    <circle style="fill:#333333;stroke:#e6e6e6;stroke-width:1.29530823;stroke-miterlimit:10" r="1.4896045" cy="16.114491" cx="16" stroke-miterlimit="10 " id="motor " />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG-transformations are supported quite differently on different browsers. IE and Opera don't support them at all. Firefox does, but not with relative value (like in your case).

So now you have three options:

- The first approach would be changing your graphics to .jpg and then everthing should work just fine. But you probably have some good arguments not doing this so here are other solutions:
- If you want to stick with .svg you could build in your animation directly in your .svg file (then you don't have to do the animation with CSS). It shouldn't be that hard as there are a lot of tutorials on the internet.
- The last solution would be using JavaScript. See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/) where the whole problem is explained very well. This article uses the GSAP library with the following code for a solution:

  ```
  TweenMax.to("#svg, #div", 2, {
      rotation:360, 
      transformOrigin:"50% 50%"
  });
  ```

---

So as a conclusion: Doing this with pure CSS is probably impossible. Even if you make it work in your browser, others probably fail displaying it correctly.